# Can my computer get hacked if I use a local server for development only? For example WAMP?

Tags: http, apache

If I use software like WAMP to test and develop my PHP websites, can someone access my computer and steal data or view my in-development websites, or even hack my computer?

Comment: The important question is if the local server is also accessible from the internet or if those inside your local network are considered threats.

Comment: By local development do you mean localhost-bound server running on your computer that sits behind ADSL in your home network. Or are you in LAN with 100 other machines connected and WAMP server listening for your IP address? 
In general, you can hardly ever be sure to be 100% safe, but you can minimize the risks to acceptable levels. WAMP is using apache2 if I recall correctly. Should be ok with proper configuration, but personally I run those in separate (virtual) instances, just to make extra level of protection.

Comment: @VladimirM So does that mean that using WAMP with the default configuration is dangerous?

Comment: @zinks , 1) you did not answer to schroeder's comment. this is an important question, because if there are no threats, you can accept more risks. 2) i don't know the version, running modules, or the configuration, so no answer there. If the default means "I don't know the actual config" then it is a danger.

Comment: You can run LAMP in a virtual machine. VirtualBox has something called "Host-only networking". It basically blocks direct access from the internet or intranet, while allowing two way communication between the host and the guest or between two guests. You can use the web browser on your Windows machine, type the VM's IP into the URL box (as if it were a second machine on the local network) but someone on a different computer won't be able to access the same VM using their browser. The VM can be headless. Bonus: You can change dev PCs without reconfiguring + you can undo mistakes using snapshots

Comment: Or if you don't mind working within a VM and using its text editor and its browser then you can disable its ability to connect to any other computer. (Host, other guests, local network, internet included.) Sort of like a poor man's alternative to an air-gapped dev PC. (But without the benefit of being truly isolated if your host machine is not secure.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible as long as you are connected to the internet, check your network configuration that could possibly expose the machine you're using which has WAMP installed.

Let's say for example your router is configured to port forward all ports to the IP of your machine and you also have a vulnerable version of WordPress installed inside your WAMP, the attacker can use that to run code on your machine and install anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MS Windows then you are already probably exposing a lot of your computer to your local network. To what extent that is then exposed to a potential hacker depends on how your network is configured.

Mysql/PHP is a really easy environment to configure, develop for and deploy code to - this is one of the reasons it is so popular, unfortunately learning how to do this securely is a lot more involved.

Setting up a (another) server on your computer running immature code will leave it a lot more exposed. As long as you restrict it to just the loopback interface should address most (>99%) of the threats.

Comment: But since there is a firewall, I am safe right? Or it doesn't really matter? And what I also  don't understand is the fact that since it is a localserver why there are risks?

Comment: And isn't Wamp configured to only allow local connections? Or do I need to do this?

Comment: If you don't know how it is configured OR you don't know how to configure it, then it is not secure. (if by "like WAMP" you really mean "only listens on loopback" you should have said so)

Answer (score 0):

I found a [series of vulnerabilities in MAMP](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/07/19/drive-by-remote-code-execution-in-mamp/) that makes it possible to trigger remote code execution through CSRF. When you visit the attacker's site, that site performs a request to localhost:8888 where your local Apache runs a vulnerable web application, triggering the remote code execution. So I would say it is a real possibility that you get hacked through your development setup.